# A pretty symmetric bipartite graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I am looking for a bipartite graph $G = (A \cup B,E)$ so that

- |A| = a.
- The vertices in $A$ all have degree $r_1$.
- The vertices in $B$ all have degree $r_2$.
- The graph is $min(r_1,r_2)$ edge-connected.

Notice that the size of $B$, which I call $b$, is determined by this information: $b = a\cdot r_1 /r_2$ and is an integer.

My idea is this: connect the first vertex of $A$ with the first $r_1$ vertices of $B$, then the next vertex of $A$ with the next $r_1$ vertices in $B$ (wrapping around), and proceed through all vertices in $A$. At the end of the process, the vertices in $A$ have the appropriate degree, and also the vertices in $B$ will have degree $r_2$ as desired.

It is nice and symmetric and I believe this will have the connectivity property I want. Do you agree? Is there an easier way, or a better way to understand this?

Comment: Note that it's possible for this graph to not be connected—for example, if $a=2r_1$ and $r_2=2$.

Comment: right. So my method doesn't work. But is there some other way to get those properties?